# Can't resolve ip by hostname on archer C7

Tags: networking, router, dns

I'm trying to access devices by using their hostname, like `ping hostname`, however since I switched to archer C7 I can't do that.

I tried to enable DNS service how I can't find it in the UI. It is also important to notice that I need to resolve hostnames from any device therefore adding the device to the hosts file isn't a solution.

I'm willing to install custom firmwere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting TP-link support I was told that the C7 doesn't support hostname resolution.

Other options are installing custom firmware or using a DNS server. I use pi hole.

Answer (score 0):

Man this has driven me nuts all week.  I realized today, it looks like an issue with wired versus wireless - and that the Archer C7 is assigning IP4 addresses to wireless, and IPv6 to wired.  I suspected it was having an issue with the routing internally.

Anyway, give this a shot:
Go to your router settings
Go to IPv6 support
Disable IPv6 for WAN (to the internet)

Additionally:
I also cleared out the default domain

I suspect that WAN connection is trying to do some resolution against your internet DNS instead of internal.  Changing that for some reason seemed to fix it.  Cheers

Comment: Actually it has nothing to do with IPv6, C7 simply does not have the DNS server to resolve hostnames. You probably revert unnecessary changes to your router. I came across 2 solutions: flashing custom firmware or making a DNS server. If you have raspberrypi I recommend using pi hole as both DNS and DHCP servers because it simply works and very easy to maintain.